# How to move files to a folder per day

Tags: shell, move

I have a folder that contains a lot of photos.

I'd like to move them on a more practictal structure, with a folder per day.

The date is extracted from the filename (e.g.                                         from `2016-08-22 16.55.26.jpg` to `2016-08-22/2016-08-22 16.55.26.jpg`)

What is the best way to do that ?

For the time being, I've created a shell script :

```
#!/bin/sh
in=~/tmp/rename/*                                                               
out=~/tmp/out                                                                   
for f in $in; do                                                                
    d=$(echo "$f" | grep -Po "\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}")                               
    mkdir -p "$out/$d"                                                          
    cp "$f" "$out/$d/"                                                          
done
```

Is there a better/easy way ?
May be with `ranger` or `rename` command ?

Comment: Do the images' filenames already have a datestamp in them (e. g. `2017-05-24-myawesomecat.png`)?

Comment: Does the shell script work? Even though the filenames contain spaces?

Comment: @nick Yes, because variables are between double quotes.

Comment: OK - the only thing I can suggest then is a simplified calculation for d: if all the filenames follow the `date space time.jpg` pattern, you can use the space to split off the desired directory: in bash, you can say `d=${f%% *}` to pick up everything  before the space, but that's bash-specific. In sh you can use `d=$(echo $f | cut -d' ' -f1)` but whether that's simpler is in the eye of the beholder.